# How to quit the entire program in Julia

Tags: julia, exit

How can I quit the entire program like this in Julia? (this is in Python):

```
import sys

def some_func():
   # do something
   sys.exit()
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You do not need to import `Base` for exiting; you can just use `exit`:

```
function some_func()
    # do something
    exit() # <- you can provide exit code if you want.
end
```

Answer (score 5):

Here's how you do it:

```
import Base
Base.exit(exit_code)
```

...where `exit_code` is the number you wish to exit with. If you omit it, it defaults to zero.

Comment: at the #julia hashtag we are not hostile ;)

Comment: :) that is good

Comment: You should not `import Base` it is unnecessary operation.